# Javascript setinterval function not working on MAC safari

Tags: javascript, safari, setinterval

I want to wait for 30 seconds and then start polling an API in every 30 seconds.
I am using following code

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    var poll = setInterval(function() {
      self.poll()
    }.bind(self), 30000)
  }, 30000);
```

although this thing works well for Chrome IE and FF 
and safari on windows.
It is not working on MAC safari.

Can anyone please guide me on this ??

regards.

Comment: What's the point of using `.bind()` when you don't use `this` within the function?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely that you're using a slightly older version of Safari.

Safari gained `Function.prototype.bind` relatively recently. What you should do is test for it, and apply a shim if absent.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility

To verify, do a simple `console.log` or `alert` of `Function.prototype.bind`. I'm guessing it'll come up `undefined`.

Comment: Or just delete the `.bind(self)` part of the code, given that the function in question references `self` and _not_ `this`, so the `.bind()` is redundant even for browsers that support it...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yeah, the code is odd. Didn't really want to get into that part of it.

Comment: thank you for you r quick reply... I tried it and it works like a charm....thank you so much for your reply..  ACTUALLY I AM VERY NEW TO   JAVASCRIPT AND DONT REALLY UNDERSTAND THE .bind(self) PART....CAN ANYONE PLEASE EXPLAIN ME ABOUT THIS.... HELP IS REALLY APPRICIATED..

Comment: @user1244197: Well, It has to do with the value of `this` in a function. The value of `this` changes based on *how* the function is invoked. Call `.bind` on a function returns a new function with the value of `this` bound to the first argument that you passed to `.bind`. That way it doesn't really matter how the function is invoked, the `this` value will be the value you expect.

Answer (score 0):

We got the same issue when our app got on to production we found a quick fix just to make our app run so its not the optimal solution. Seems that Safari is not calling setInterval unless there is a changed variable/value on each cycle. So we console logged the current time so every time there is a change and it worked. Correct me if I am missing anything.

```
const id = setInterval(() => {
let _time = Date.now();
console.log(_time)
      refetch();
    }, 5000);
```